# XFS Trial barrier write failure message in dmesg

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs

I'm noticing the following lines in dmesg when an XFS volume is being mounted

```
dm-1: Disabling barriers, trial barrier write failed
```

Anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 2):

You should modify the mount options. Add `nobarrier` to the options in `/etc/fstab` for the partition.

[See Red Hat's note about it](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/writebarrieronoff.html).

*To mitigate the risk of data corruption during power loss, some storage devices use battery-backed write caches. Generally, high-end arrays and some hardware controllers use battery-backed write cached. However, because the cache's volatility is not visible to the kernel, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 enables write barriers by default on all supported journaling file systems.*

Comment: nobarrier also massively increases performance and you don't get so many flush kernel threads using valuable resources.